# Python: Query about the way caching happens using descriptors

Tags: python, descriptor

I was trying out caching using descriptors using below code

```
class TestDesc(object):
    def __init__(self,test):
        self.test = test

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        value =  instance.__dict__[self.test.__name__] = self.test(instance)
        return value

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass

class MyClass(object):
    @TestDesc
    def func(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        return "I am very slow"

c = MyClass()
print(c.func)
print(c.func)
```

Both the calls to print take 5 seconds which is not how it should work. But if I remove the `__set__` method that I had added, caching works fine. 
I couldnt figure out why caching does not work as expected with the `__set__` method in the descriptor class.
Any pointers appreciated. I am using Python 3.4.1

Ref: http://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit upon the difference between a *data descriptor* and a regular descriptor. Data descriptors are handled before instance attributes, while regular descriptors are handled after.

See [*Invoking Descriptors*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) in the reference documenation:

> If the descriptor defines `__set__()` and/or `__delete__()`, it is a data descriptor; if it defines neither, it is a non-data descriptor.
>
> [...]
>
> Data descriptors with `__set__()` and `__get__()` defined **always override a redefinition in an instance dictionary**. In contrast, non-data descriptors can be overridden by instances.

Emphasis mine.

And from the [*Descriptor HowTo Guide*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol):

> If an object defines both `__get__()` and `__set__()`, it is considered a data descriptor. Descriptors that only define `__get__()` are called non-data descriptors (they are typically used for methods but other uses are possible).
>
> Data and non-data descriptors differ in how overrides are calculated with respect to entries in an instance’s dictionary. **If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a data descriptor, the data descriptor takes precedence**. If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a non-data descriptor, the dictionary entry takes precedence.

Your `TestDecs` descriptor has a `__set__` method, so it is considered a data descriptor, and the instance attribute is not consulted to allow the setter to always be invoked.

Comment: I guess the heart of the code is in "value =  instance.__dict__[self.test.__name__] = self.test(instance)". So you mean if I define __set__, it works like "value = self.test(instance)" otherwise as "value = instance.__dict__[self.test.__name__]" ?

Comment: @RohitSasikumar: that line sets an attribute on the instance with the exact same name as the property; for a non-data descriptor that then overrides all future access for that name. If you have a `__set__` method, making this a data-descriptor, the `__get__` method is always going to be called, so in your getter you'd need to check if you already set a cached value and return that instead of calling the method.